# Nessus 8.13 Install on Kali or Ubuntu: /etc/init.d/nessusd: command not found

Tags: kali-linux, init-script, sysvinit

I really need some help with this issue I am having. I am trying to install Nessus scanner on either my Kali 2020.2 or Ubuntu 20.04 LTS VMs on Virtual Box. Granted I have tried this install on both Kali and Ubuntu with the same outcome.  I complete the following steps per the instructions:

**STEP 3 is where my problem exists**

1. Access & retrieve the Activation Code
2. Download & Install Nessus per instructions using the command

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i Nessus-8.13.1-debian6_amd64.deb
   ```
3. Start the service with command

   ```
   /etc/init.d/nessusd start
   ```

After trying to start the service I get the following error message

> `sudo: /etc/init.d/nessusd: command not found`

**Troubleshooting steps**

- Tried looking for Nessusd under `/etc/init.d/` and there is nothing related to Nessus
- Ran command

  ```
  cat -v /etc/init.d/nessusd
  ```

  with the following results:

  > `cat: /etc/init.d/nessusd: No such file or directory`
- I have run the command `dpkg-query -l` which I do see Nessus there
- I have logged out of the user account and logged into Root account to check if `nessusd` would be listed there under `/etc/init.d` location, and again it is not.
- I have tried rebooting and also re-installing to see if I get a different outcome and no difference.

I am lost on how to fix this issue. I have spent the last several hours trying to find a remedy. If anyone knows how to fix this issue I would be very grateful. I am trying to get through the TryHackMe lessons and I am currently on the Nessus lesson and would like to finish it. Again, I have tried this on both Kali and Ubuntu and I keep getting the same results so curious if maybe this is a known issue or bug?

Thanks in advance for any help! **Happy New Year!! 2021!!**

Comment: Did you also look in `/opt/nessus/sbin` for the `nessusd` executable? I'm just looking at the file listing of the `deb` file... The installation instructions sees to possibly have been written for an older version of the tool.

Comment: I do see 3 files listed in the /opt/nessus/sbin/ location. I see nessuscli, nessusd, and nessus-service. So based on this do I just need to run it from there with the following: /opt/nessus/sbin/nessusd start ?

Comment: That seems to have worked. I tried that and its running. The strange thing I ran systemctl status nessusd for verification and it shows active but says its been running for over an hour. lol Thanks for your help. Not need to finish the install. I really appreciate it!

Comment: If you want to add a proper answer to this, then please do so (then accept it). Otherwise I'll close this as "problem went away".

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
systemctl enable --now nessusd
```

Verify it:

```
systemctl status nessusd
```

You get an error because the service file is under:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/nessusd.service
```

and not `/etc/init.d/`

Comment: Looks like nessus moved to a systemd service file and they forgot to account for that in their own documentation.